save_transaction(user_name, ticker, 0, sell_price, quantity, total_investment, None, date)Error binding parameter 4: type 'tuple' is not supported

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 211
    209 for date, gain_loss, ticker, sell_price, quantity in zip(selling_dates, gains_losses, suggested_stocks['Ticker'], suggested_stocks['Sell_Price'], suggested_stocks['Qty_to_Buy']):
    210     total_investment = sell_price * quantity  # Calculate the actual total investment
--> 211     save_transaction(user_name, ticker, 0, sell_price, quantity, total_investment, None, date)
    213 # Retrieve user portfolio and display
    214 portfolio = get_portfolio(user_name)

Cell In[23], line 187, in save_transaction(user_name, ticker, buy_price, sell_price, quantity, total_investment, buy_date, sell_date)
    186 def save_transaction(user_name, ticker, buy_price, sell_price, quantity, total_investment, buy_date, sell_date):
--> 187     cursor.execute('''
    188     SELECT * FROM portfolios 
    189     WHERE user_name=? AND ticker=? AND buy_date=? AND sell_date=?
    190     ''', (user_name, ticker, buy_date, sell_date))
    191     existing_transaction = cursor.fetchone()
    193     if existing_transaction:

ProgrammingError:
Error binding parameter 4: type 'tuple' is not supported

creating SQL db in Python
